# How to create a second database schema in the same RDS instance on Amazon RDS?

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

does anyone know how to create a second database in the same machine using Oracle?

I have 1 database already. But I have not clue on how to create a second one using the same RDS instance.

any help or advice is welcome :)

I looks like I have to create a second user and that will create the schema. Now looking how to do this.

Comment: RDS = Amazon Relational Database Service. Its just a managed database instance.

Answer (score 5):

the user you created during rds setup (Master user/pass) is more or less like a sysdba user with which you can create other schema users.

something like this

sqlplus /@TEST

SQL> create user  identified by  default tablespace ;

User created.

SQL> grant connect to ;

Grant succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing terminology here. Are you talking about database instances, or about users/schemas?

Your database instance can have up to 30 users/schemas. http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#2

You can launch up to 20 database instances if you like. http://aws.amazon.com/rds/#details

Comment: The 30 schemas per Oracle DB isn't current. Unlimited number of schemas in one instance it is, now.